# Error when trying to install SQL Server 2022 Express Edition

Tags: windows, installation, sql-server-express, sql-server-2022

I have been trying to install SQL Server 2022 Express Edition on my machine but I always get the same error which in summary mentions the following: "The account that is running SQL Server Setup does not have one or all the following rights: the right to manage auditing and the security log, and the right to debug programs"

The last time I tried, something like this appeared on the screen (Example, this is an image from another version, mine is 2022):

[image: Error]

I have tried to install with the administrator user and using "Run as administrator" but still without success

Comment: That image is of SQKL Server 2019, not 2022. Though if you are getting that error, that does suggest that your user doesn't have permission and aren't right clicking and selecting "Run as administrator".

Comment: It is not my image, it is one that I got from the internet, I have only put it as an example and yes I am using "Run as an administrator"

Comment: This might help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/760077/set-up-account-privileges-failure-when-installing